First Child in Horizontal Scroll Carousel Has 0x0 Size (Width and Height)
I've been working on a simple product page to practice and better understand key concepts.
However, I'm encountering an issue with the .carousel grid inside a media query. The first element renders with a width and height of 0x0, and I can't figure out why. Additionally, the gap property isn't being applied, even though it's defined within the media query.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Product Carrousel</title>
  <style>

    * { /* reset the styles */
      font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    section {
      margin-top: 48px;
    }

    main {
      margin-top: 48px;
    }

    img {
      max-width: 100%;
      border-radius: 10px;
    }

    .container {
      max-width: 75%;
      margin: 0 auto; /* align content */
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; /* create 2 columns of the same size */
      gap: 24px;
    }

    @media (max-width: 780px) {
      .container {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
      }

      .carousel {
        grid-auto-flow: column;
        grid-auto-columns: 100%;
        overflow-x:scroll;
      }

      .grid-item {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }

      .grid-item:first-child {
        outline: orange;
      }
    }

    .carousel {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr; /* for two columns: repeat(2, minmax(100, 1fr)) */
      grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
      gap: 8px;
      scroll-snap-type: inline mandatory;
    }
    
    .grid-item {
      height: auto;
      scroll-snap-align: center;
    }

    .product-info {
      position:sticky;
      top: 3rem;
      background-color: lightseagreen;
      max-height: 200px;

      h1 {
        padding-top: 0;
        line-height: 1.5rem;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    <div class="container">

      <div class="carousel">
        <img class="grid-item" id="1" src="https://placehold.co/800x800" alt="default">
        <img class="grid-item" id="2" src="https://placehold.co/800x800" alt="default">
        <img class="grid-item" id="3" src="https://placehold.co/800x800" alt="default">
        <img class="grid-item" id="4" src="https://placehold.co/800x800" alt="default">
        <img class="grid-item" id="5" src="https://placehold.co/800x800" alt="default">
        <img class="grid-item" id="6" src="https://placehold.co/800x800" alt="default">
      </div>

      <div class="product-info">
        <h1>Product Title</h1>
        <p>Product Information</p>
        <p>$99.99</p>
        <button>Add to cart</button>
      </div>

    </div>
</main>
</body>
</html>

Image Of Firefox Inspector
I've tried adjusting the width, min-width, max-width, height, and other size-related properties, but the issue persists. It doesn't seem to be related to the scroll behavior, since even after removing that property, only 5 out of the 6 elements are visible. I also tested by adding more elements and commenting out the first one, but the issue remains—the new first child always has a size of 0x0.

I fixed the two problems this way:
To fix the problem with the div of 0x0 size, I changed the next property of my carousel class.
@media (max-width: 780px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
  }
}

To fix the problem with the gap, I only put the media query at the end of my styles.
Link to the CodeSandbox

Try defining a height in the grid-item:
.grid-item {
  height: 200px; /* Set a fixed height for visibility */
  scroll-snap-align: center;
}

For the gap issue try setting the carousel class as:
.carousel {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 8px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}

